# RubyMine with Rubocop - How to Reformat?

Tags: rubymine

I have RuboCop installed with Rubymine and the inspection errors for rubocop are showing up properly.

Running <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> converts the code to rubymine style that **conflicts** with rubocop style.

For example:

```
some_array = 10.times.map {|index| index * 3}   # rubymine
some_array = 10.times.map { |index| index * 3 } # rubocop
```

rubocop puts spaces inside of inline blocks. a small thing I know. but rubymine autoformats without spaces so I have a crapton of of inspection notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rubymine, go to Settings → Editor → Code Style → Ruby and ensure you have the ***Spaces around curly braces*** option checked.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is an easier way to make rubymine match rubocop?

Comment: If you're talking about how to make Rubymine obey preconfigured Rubocop rules, then there is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15896) about this and it is planned to be implemented in the **2017.2 Rubymine version**.